# Amplify install error "Failed to get profile: Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of undefined." on windows

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am following the [amplify tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/guides/deploy-webapp-amplify/module-one/) provided by AWS. The `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` command is resulting in `"failed to install amplify binary"`.

When I first did this I did not notice an error and continued through the tutorial until the: `amplify init -y command`.

Originaly the error I got for the above command was `'Failed to get profile: Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of undefined'`.

I then uninstalled and reinstalled `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` getting the same first error every time I have tried this `"failed to install amplify binary"` and continuing to the `amplify init -y command` I get `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\caleb\.amplify\bin\amplify.exe'`.

I am assuming that is because of the installation error. To try and troubleshoot the installation error I have done '`npm cache clean --force` and `npm rebuild`

I am not sure what else to try, my node version is v16.17.0 after updating from v16.14.0 hoping it would fix the issue.

Edit: After messing with this for hours I reset my computer and I can now `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` just fine but getting to `amplify init -y command` I still get the original error: `'Failed to get profile: Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of undefined'`.

Comment: Were you using IAM or IAM Identity Center?

Answer (score 1):

Resetting my machine made the installation error "failed to install amplify binary" go away, and thus after going through `amplify configure` again the command `amplify init -y` works as expected. I tried this 7-8 times and updated, reinstalled etc nodejs many times which made no difference, I could not find any other search results for "failed to install amplify binary" so decided to post but resetting my machine magically fixed this.

Comment: I would be keen to hear what your setup includes
IAM or IAM Identity Center?

Answer (score 1):

I found running amplify init and working through options manually allowed me to successfully initialize the project and continue on with the tutorial.

Comment: I would be keen to hear what your setup includes
IAM or IAM Identity Center?